# How to give option for multiple templates for one view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates

I have an application in rails3 where i want to give user an option to choose a template from defaults (4 or 5 templates) to view his records.

the approach i am working on is to sent user on setting page from where he will select the template he want to use and on the basis of that setting the template will be rendered.

This looks simple but i am not sure this will work for me, please suggest me any alternative.
Please note i am talking about PDF formats.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a Setting model with a string attribute template.

You would let the user save the setting through a normal controller action.

Then on the controller where you want your pdf template to show, you could do something like this.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @setting = Setting.find(params[:setting_id]) # Retrieve the setting instance
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf { render setting.template }
    end
  end
end
```

This will render the template named after the template the user has selected and is stored on setting as a string.